# Rained in/over/during

Tags: prepositions, sentence-choice

Please tell me the difference, even if a little, between the following sentences. I have looked at previous threads on this issue, but they don't address all the three prepositions at once. So please help me.

1. It has rained ***in*** the last five days.
2. It has rained ***over*** the last five days.
3. It has rained ***during*** the last five days.

Comment: Add a 4th. "It has rained the last five days".

Answer (score 1):

The are the same to me, a Chinese English Learner:-)